# Javascript not working when 'alert; is removed

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS on my html and my obervations are:

1) When I removed the line for "alert" display it is not working as expected, the SAVE button is not trigerring when clicked.

2) Even with the "alert", it is not working in CHROME.

```
function save() {
  alert('View Full List triggered!');
    var $form = $('.fancybox-inner').find('[data-area="funder-detail"]');

    $form.on('click', '[data-action="save-funder"]', function () {
    var selected1 = $form.find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
    if ($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length == 0) {
      parent.$.fancybox.close();
    } else {
      document.getElementById("txtFunder").value = selected1;
      parent.$.fancybox.close();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Where do you call that save method? in the onload? Maybe provide a working jsfiddle

Comment: The save method is triggered on the main.cshtml. My JS is also included on this main.cshtml

<span style="font-weight:normal" onclick="save()">@Html.ActionLink(Strings.Link_ViewFullList, "FundersFullList", new { id = 1 }, new { @class = "fancybox fancybox.ajax" })</span>


Then the contents of the fancybox including the [Save] button are on a different cshtml.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the script runs too early, when the form is not yet in the DOM?
This can happen when the script tag is in the header.

Try moving the script tag in front of the closing  tag.

Comment: How do I apply this @Arnelism? Sorry, new to JS.

Comment: @JADE, move your script tag below the DOM elements that it manipulates.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by using onclick="setTimeout(save, 1000)"